# How to resolve ? Error:(51, 23) error: no suitable method found for setButton method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How can I resolve this error:

```
Error:(51, 23) error: no suitable method found for setButton(String,<anonymous OnClickListener>)
method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,Message) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,OnClickListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And my code is :=

```
 alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
           alertDialog.setButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int which){
                   finish();
               }
           });

            alertDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: change `setButton` to `setPositiveButton`

Comment: Changed it but does not worked out sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :=
Change your code :

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
           alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int which){
                   finish();
               }
           });
```